# Alternative for MS Silverlight in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, silverlight

We are currently using MS Silverlight for some sites in SP2010 On-Prem (referenced the .xap files in webparts). These sites would soon be migrated to SharePoint online.
Can anyone share the approach taken for replacing Silverlight in SharePoint online?
I had read a bit about MS Blazor, but I don't think it would be applicable in my scenario, since it has to be a client side component. Any help would be appreciated, since I'm not at all able to find any definitive approach anyone has taken for this migration.

ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to rewrite them all over from scratch in client side technology. Sorry, there's no migration path for Silverlight. Those Silverlight web parts have had a good run.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there is no way to migrate Silverlight to another language.

Silverlight was a sort of temporary language until CSS3 and JavaScript. Today, the best way, it to "migrate" manually your Silverlight solution to JavaScript (that can be TypeScript or any client-side language).

Rebuild your "apps" into modern client-side code is really beneficial and you will optimize them for sure.

Take a look at SPFx: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview